# Slow CURL request PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl, post, request

Im having a issue with a POST request to an API that my company has on a google appengine, while the script that makes the request is on another non-google server.

Im making two consecutive requests to the API, the first (POST) is made to get the access token while the second one (GET) is made to retrieve the actual data I need.

The code is the following:

```
switch ($method){
    case "POST":
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        break;
    case "PUT":
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                              
        break;
    default:
        if ($data)
            $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
}
// OPTIONS:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        
if(!is_null($headers)){
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
}
 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// EXECUTE:

$result = curl_exec($curl);
        
curl_close($curl);

return $result;
```

The request time is extremely variable, from less than 1 sec to more than 255.

Looking at the curl_getinfo output I see that the tough part is the `connect_time`, and it becomes very long mainly (more frequently) in the second request, that is the GET one.

I tried many parameters for cURL options, like forcing IPV6 or IPV4 nothing changed, maybe it goes better for 20 times and then the issue happens again.

Thank you in advance for the help, ask me for other details if needed.

Comment: You cannot control the response time of the other server

Comment: What is your question? Do you have any reason to think that the server response time can be improved somehow? Unless you control its hadware/software/networking configuration, you are _stuck_ with what they're offering you.

Comment: So it's an issue related to the sever im making the request to, not to the request itself?

Comment: Could this be a latency issue? Is your non-google server in a different geographic region to your GAE? Could you try a ping test between your servers for example? It would be good to test this over a time period and compare them. Also, what API are you using?

Comment: No they are both in Europe, anyway I will try to do a ping test. The API is made in Laravel with OAuth 2.0 Authorization